# Rails Coffeescript check if a record exists

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

In a Rails view, I can use the following to see if a record exists:

```
Workorder.exists?(id: 1)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in CoffeeScript?

This coffeescript code seems to work - but, I imagine there is a better way?:

```
$("#goto-workorder").click ->
  serverused =  window.location.href.split('/h')[0]
  bootbox.prompt "Enter ID" , (woid) ->
    if woid is null
      alert("Enter Number")
    else
      $.ajax
        url: "/workorders/" + woid
        type: "GET"
        data:
          _method: 'get'
        success: (resp) ->
          window.location.replace(serverused + "/workorders/" + woid)
    return
```

Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: @SSR That's completely unrelated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no simpler way to check for the existence of a database record in client-side CoffeeScript. The browser cannot know *anything* about the server-side state except by contacting the server.

In Rails (or any other web framework), if you wanted to test for the existence of a record, you would create a server-side end-point for your client-side code to consume.

Comment: Not sure if it's the best way, but I ended up using the ajax GET to test if the record is in the db.